# Can a moderator please merge my two accounts, one of which was created before I registered?

Tags: support

My very first question on TGO, [Where can we go backpacking out West under 8,500 feet that has much of the feel of much higher altitudes](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8873/where-can-we-go-backpacking-out-west-under-8-500-feet-that-has-much-of-the-feel), is stuck in the account I was assigned before I registered.  This question does not appear in the list of questions in my active account.

This is undesirable for several reasons, not least of which is that I could not then, and cannot now, accept the fine answer I got from gerrit.  Also, it is messy to have my first question in a little box that is hard to get to.

I would appreciate any help you can give on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is fairly common, enough so that there are multiple posts on it over on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/154443)

To merge any two accounts, follow the procedure outlined on the ["User Merge" help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

> If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please sign into either account, visit the contact form and select ‘I need to merge user profiles’. After you contact us, the Stack Exchange Team will reach out to verify that you own both accounts. If we can confirm your ownership, we will initiate a merge.

If you can't remember how to log in, press on the words "go here" on that page. It will link you to a page where you enter the email address you used to create the account you are trying to sign into.